# How to get the payment details in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.1

I have added account number field in payment data.

I need to display it under payment details in **sales_order_view, sales_order_invoice, sales_order_creditmemos.**

SO, I have choosen `magento/payment/block/info/instruction` block...but i can't get the payment details in all mentioned layouts.

How do that... Or else any other way for do it.

Ideas welcome...